# writeToFile fails to save 4K video with 40 min recording in document directory

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, nsdata, document-directory

`writeToFile` fails to save 4K video with 50 min recording in document directory

```
BOOL videoSuccess = [[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:videoURL] writeToFile:videoPath atomically:YES];
```

So videoSuccess returns false

Video Url:

> file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/5C6C1826-B1B9-4F8C-BEFA-8842166B38CC/tmp/output.mov

Video Path:

> /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/5C6C1826-B1B9-4F8C-BEFA-8842166B38CC/Documents/20180808160025.mp4

---

Got solution:
Use `moveItemAtPath` instead of `writeToFile` or `copyItemAtPath`

```
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] moveItemAtPath:videoURL toPath:videoPath error:&error];
```

Comment: can you show your videoURL and videoPath

Comment: @RakeshPatel I have updated the question with videoURL and videoPath

Comment: is it solved???

Comment: Show your full code..how you store video at videourl?

Comment: @RakeshPatel - Its working with 'moveItemAtPath' but fails for 'writeToFile' and 'copyItemAtPath'

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you try to copy content from one directory path to another at that time don't rewrite whole content just use copy method.

```
            do
            {
              try FileManager.default.copyItem(at: videoURL, to: videoPath)
             }
            catch
            {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
```

And also check your url is getting proper or not.